# How to create a Toggle button in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am wondering how can I use Radio button as a toggle in Angular2.

What I need is if Radio button value is changes I want to get that value without creating a form.

Any help please.

[edit]:

I did:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender">Gender</label><br>
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male&nbsp;
                  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
              </div>
```

in a form and getting value of gender in a form deails. But I dont want to use form for this.

Comment: @Nicro: Thanks for replying, please see the edits i have used radio buttons in a form but not getting how to use it without a form element. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your component

```
public gender = [
        'male',
        'female'
    ];
onGenderChange(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

in your html

```
<div *ngFor="let value of gender">
    <input (change)="onGenderChange($event.target.value)" type="radio" name="gender" value="{{ value }}">{{ value }}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Can you please tell how can I set any one as detault checked

Comment: [checked]="value == 'male'". Is it what you need?

Comment: thanks, one thing more, I am in need to give value as a variable. I tried checked="value == {{is_subscribed}}" and [checked]="value == {{is_subscribed}}". Can you please help. A lot thanks again

Comment: [checked]="value == is_subscribed"